# How to output the arguments of a Function in the Function itself

Tags: php

```
<?php


$l = 4000;

function flip($h, $t)
{

    if ($h + $t <= 29) {
        $a = mt_rand(0, 1);
        if ($a == 1) {
            flip($h + 1, $t);
        } else {
            flip($h, $t + 1);
        }

    } else {

        echo "$h,$t" . "</br>";
    }

}

$ar = array( "test");


for ($i = 0; $i <= $l; $i++) {
    array_push($ar, flip(0, 0));
}


?>
```

My code is supposed to give the number of tails and heads upon spinnings 30 times. And this process is done 4000 times. I want to store all the results of the 4000 times in an array using the above code. But I think the way I defined by flip is wrong. I didn't know how to store the value of the arguments of flip after it is done therefore I used an echo.

When i run this code.. for some reason it is printing out all the answers like this : http://searchr.us/testing/ip.php instead of just making an array. I have pin pointed that the way I took the vfilanl values of flip wrong. Can someone tell me the **difference** between **echo** , **print** and how DO i use return. When i just use return(); after echo.It gives me an error.

Please clarify my doubt on how I can output these values.

Comment: You need to use [`return`](http://www.php.net/return) instead of `echo`/`print`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use something like this:

```
<?php

function flip($h, $t)
{

    if ($h + $t > 29) return $h . ',' . $t;
    $a = mt_rand(0, 1);
    return $a == 1 ? flip($h + 1, $t) : flip($h, $t + 1);

}

$ar = array( "test");

$l = 4000;
for ($i = 0; $i <= $l; ++$i) {
    array_push($ar, flip(0, 0));
}

?>
```

Note that [`echo`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php) outputs to the client.

But you want to decide what you get when you call `flip`, and that is done using [`return`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.return.php).

Comment: Hello, I see your code is moreorless same. But now I have replaced echo in my code with return. ignoring the array part. I tried getting the answer for flip by doing this 'print flip(0,0)' how come i didnt get any answer?

Comment: @SaiKrishnaDeep It works for me if I use `echo flip(0,0), '<br />';` inside the loop. With `print flip(0,0) . '<br />';` works too but concatenating strings is slower.

Comment: <?php


$l = 4000;

function flip($h, $t)
{
    
    if ($h + $t <= 29) {
        $a = mt_rand(0, 1);
        if ($a == 1) {
            flip($h + 1, $t);
        } else {
            flip($h, $t + 1);
        }
        
    } else {
        
         return $h . ',' . $t;
    }
    
}

echo flip(0,0) . '<br />';



?>

That is my now.. Still doesnt work..

Comment: @SaiKrishnaDeep You must add return: `return flip($h + 1, $t);` and `return flip($h, $t + 1);`.

Comment: Thanks a lot Oriol! Could tell me what is the reason behind this change and how exactly does return do the trick? Can you provide me a link if it is too laborious to explain? :) Thanks, Sai

Comment: @SaiKrishnaDeep Not at all :) . See for example http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.return.php . Keep in mind that there are two types of functions: functions that answer your question (arguments), and questions that do things for you. The first ones need `return` to give the answer, and the second ones can return something or not. In your case, you ask how many tails and heads, so you need a `return` to get that answer. An example of the second type is `echo`: it outputs some data for you, and doesn't answer (return) anything.